# Combine two checkout steps magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

I am looking to combine the 2 checkout steps of Magento 2 into one page. Does anybody know a solution for this?

Comment: you mean , shipping address , and payment method? They are already in a page.

Comment: Okay I just saw that indeed. I want to make it onepage without two steps. So I think I could redesign the page with CSS